# Is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]$ integrally closed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory

I know that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is integrally closed, also $F(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}])/F(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}])=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]/\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is an algebraic field extension, so by a theorem from commutative algebra any element $\alpha$ of $F(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}])$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ if and only if $\mu_{\alpha,F(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}])}(X)\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}][X]$. Since for $\alpha=a+b\sqrt{3}\in F(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}])=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ $\mu_{\alpha,F(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}])}(X)=X^2-2aX+a^2-3b^2$ this is equivalent to $2a,a^2-3b^2\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$. Trying to derive further conditions for this to show that then $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$(since then i would receive the result that $\overline{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]}^{\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]}=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]$ and hence that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]$ is integrally closed) i stumble upon ugly equations that seem very tedious to work through, so i was wondering if anyone knows a better approach to this problem or if there is a simple counterexample that i am overlooking.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}}{2}$ is not in this ring, although it is integral over it. Hence the ring is not integrally closed.